# Docker images and container names completion in Bash for Windows

Tags: linux, bash

I have Docker for Windows, and I have recently started using Bash for Windows. I managed to make docker in bash show containers and images from my windows by adding the following lines to my `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin"
```

(So I did not use `apt-get install`)

And I also declared an alias in `.bashrc` like that: `alias docker='docker.exe'`

Now when I'm typing `docker ps` it will show containers running on my windows.

At first, I had no command completion at all. Typing `docker lo` followed by pressing tab did nothing (instead of completing to `docker logs` for example, so I googled and stumbled upon the following command:

`sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/cli/master/contrib/completion/bash/docker -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker`

Now I have command completion, but no completion for image and container names.

Is there any way to make it work? Should I have directly installed docker on the ubuntu subsystem?

(I wasn't sure if this is the right stackexchange for this or askubuntu. If I should ask this somewhere else please let me know)

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Zsh**:

Place the completion script in your `/path/to/zsh/completion` (typically `~/.zsh/completion/)`:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.zsh/completion
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/1.22.0/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker-compose > ~/.zsh/completion/_docker-compose
```

Include the directory in your `$fpath` by adding in `~/.zshrc`:

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
```

Make sure `compinit` is loaded or do it by adding in `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i
```

Then reload your shell:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

Original source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#zsh

Comment: I appreciate the response, but since asking this question I switched to using Ubuntu, so I have no way to test if it works. If anyone else runs into the same issue and comments that it works, I'll accept this as the answer :)